# How to export a variable after fetching data from API in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, constants, export, fetch-api

I need to export a const from a jsx file. Currently it is set to static values and is working fine.

Now the problem is I need to pass data, for this const, from the API.

So, how can I export this const after getting data from the API call?

I've tried below code but it is not working!

```
let response = async()=>{ return fetch("http://localhost:54982/api/Admin/GetRouteLinks")  }
let resData = async()=>{ return response.json() }

let dashRoutes = resData;
export default dashRoutes;
```

Comment: I suggest you export a function that returns the data that was fetched from the API.

Comment: It will give me function not the variable which I want to use!!!

Comment: That right! You will have access to the function, so you will be able to call it, and get the data you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  export a function
(getData) is ur Ajax data request

```
import {getData} from '';

export const nameFunc = () => {
   getData().then(data => {
       /* do what you want to do in promise resolve callback function */
   })
}
```

Comment: It is not a class. It is just a jsx file from where I am exporting constants required in the website